# ERROR 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, sql

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{
>       dpto_id INT FOREIGN KEY,
>       ubicacion VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
>   } at line 2

al crear esta tabla

```
CREATE TABLE ubicaciondpto
{
  dpto_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  ubicacion VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY
};
```

Comment: Conteste tu pregunta por que aunque el primer error es un *typo* y pudiera terminar cerrada por eso, tienes un segundo error que indica declaraste mal las 2 llaves primarias que ocupas tener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dos errores principales.

**Error número 1**

De sintaxis, la declaración de todas las columnas que componen a tu tabla, van dentro de paréntesis `()` y no dentro de llaves `{}`

**Error número 2**

De declaración de llaves primarias, si bien es cierto que puedes declarar una llave compuesta, la forma en que lo haces es incorrecta, por que te va a regresar un error de este tipo:

> Multiple primary key defined

Entonces la forma de solucionarlo, es crear una estructura del modo siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE ubicaciondpto
(
dpto_id INT,
ubicacion VARCHAR(50),
PRIMARY KEY(dpto_id, ubicacion)
);
```

- Removimos el atributo `PRIMARY KEY` de cada columna
- Declaramos un tercer renglón donde usamos el atributo `PRIMARY KEY` pasandole como argumentos las dos columnas que deseamos sean llaves primarias

Comment: +1, aunque diría que, más exactamente, no es que se pueda declarar más de una clave primaria, es que se puede declarar una clave primaria  compuesta de más de una columna.